# How to determine App download date in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have uploaded a free app into app store and if a user downloads it and then if he/she delete the app and again after some months if they download the same app then at this point how can I get the first download date of my free app on which the user have downloaded my app for the first time

Answer (score 6):

At first launch of your app, you could store the date in the keychain. The keychain item will not be removed when the app is deleted from the device.
So when the user re-installs the app, you again check the keychain for presence of your first launch date.

Comment: You beat me to it! I was just going to say that.

Comment: The trouble with using the keychain is that a significant percentage of people won't do a backup prior to upgrading their device. This caused the keychain to get lost. So, make sure you have a plan to deal with this because it will occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flurry to see how many time it is been downloaded but you can not get idea about when it got downloaded and who downloaded and who downloaded it how many times.

To do this you can write custom database and whenever your app istalled successfully you can insert the UDID and Installation date in that database using webservice.

I hope you understand what I try to explain.

Just to tell you that apple is rejecting apps if you are storing UDID without device owner's permission so add a message at start up that you are going to save the UDID else Apple may reject it with Ios6 release.

Thank

Comment: Jigar I dont want to save the user's udid and etc in my server.
Apple shows the option "install" instead of "free" if the user tries to download the app for the second time. I just want to know whether it was possible for us also to know when the user has downloaded the app\

Comment: in that case you can use flurry or tool like that

Comment: Both options are good enough & roughly depends on kind of requirement you have...

Comment: `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` has been deprecated, so I wouldn't recommend any new code try to use that.  You can try to make some other kind of unique identifier (maybe MAC-based), but the actual UDID might not be a good choice.

Comment: Just to tell you that apple is rejecting apps if you are storing UDID without device owner's permission so add a message at start up that you are going to save the UDID else Apple may reject it with Ios6 release.

Comment: @user1184202 :- you can track installation history and installation count if you follow.